# How to take screenshot (using idevicescreenshot) on a remote machine

Tags: iphone, macos, screenshot

I can take a screenshot when my local machine is connected to a device using `idevicescreenshot` `original_screenshot.tiff`

```
sips -s format png original_screenshot.tiff --out converted_screenshot.png
```

but when I try to take a screenshot from a remote device connected to a remote machine like this:

```
ssh $sshUser@$sshHost "idevicescreenshot original_screenshot.tiff ;
sips -s format png original_screenshot.tiff --out converted_screenshot.png;
exit"
```

-- I get a black screenshot.

Any idea ?

Comment: Is there a user logged in to the remote machine via the UI, and is the device awake?